# From hybrid bicycle to MTB

Tags: hybrid-bike

I have a 2013 Giant Escape 3. I intend to use it as an MTB or gravel bike. Please advise changes, if any, that I need to make to use the bike as an off road bicycle.

Comment: To start with, just try it as it is now.  Then you can evaluate what is failing for you.  Tyres are likely high up, but your existing road tyres will be adequate for many of the tamer tracks.

Comment: Thank you. Sounds wiser rather than visiting the Bike shop for now

Comment: Start by riding around a local grass park, not a sealed pathway, and see how you go.

Comment: "Gravel bike" and "MTB" are quite different things.  Most gravel bikes have no or minimal suspension while the vast majority of modern MTBs have at least front suspension.  My tourer and my hybrid are both good as gravel bikes (though I don't normally run the most suitable tyres) but would be poor MTBs even if I do keep thinking of taking them on the local blue trail

Comment: @Chris H agreed. I would be initially treading on Gravel surfaces, uphill and downhill. Nothing serious. Am curious if a Hybrid frame can withstand such rough riding ?

Comment: If you're not too heavy, and you unweight the saddle for big bumps, you'll be fine.  I've probably done more off-road riding on each of my hybrid and my tourer than my MTB.  This [time lapse of a ride I did a couple of years ago](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vifFQ8EHTRY) was on my tourer (steel frame, drop bars, 35mm tyres).  Gravel roads start at 22s, and around 35s it gets a bit rough (like dropping off 20+cm high rocks)

Answer (score 4):

> I intend to use it as an mtb or gravel bike

I assume you mean "MTB" as "cross-country", and I assume you do not plan to take part in competitions, except in those meant for absolute beginners.

[image: Giant Escape 3]

The most important thing you could have done is to change tires to the widest the frame/fork would fit. However, this bike already comes with tires 35 mm wide, and I am afraid those are as big as one can squeeze there. You might want to change them  to ones with more "off-road" tread, but that would mean sacrificing the width, and I am not sure it is a reasonable trade off.

The next thing would be lowering the gear range available to you. Front of your bike has a triple with 28/38/48 teeth, and the rear cassette is 14-34 teeth. You are unlikely to ever use the front 48 teeth chainring offroad, while having a smaller smallest chainring is desirable; something like 22/34 at the front is what I typically use. Similarly, he rear cassette should have as big teeth count as possible, e.g. 11-36 or even 11-42 are likely to be achievable on the rear wheel hub you have now.

Changing gears as I described means you would have to change *everything* around them: rear and front cogs, rear and front derailleurs, rear and front shifters, the chain and possibly the cranks. Of course, you might be able to just find a bigger cassette or tighter front chainrings compatible with your existing system, but that is unlikely given that your drivetrain uses 7-speeds at the back.

The amount of changes I listed (+ installation costs) would cost you as much as a new bike. Your current bike is really just tuned for the city transportation task.

So if you are serious about offroad riding, just go and sell the current bike and buy another one more suited for the task. Otherwise, just try riding your current bicycle where you want it; I'd say nothing prevents it to conquer regular gravel roads and easiest singletrack. Lower the tire pressure to have a bit of more cushion, swap in decent pedals to avoid feet slipping, take it slow, know your limits, and have fun!

Comment: Wonderful. Yes I do intend to enjoy limited off-road areas and gravel. No shocks so maybe shouldn't consider jumping off curbs (earlier bmx days enjoyment). Current tires are 700x32... was doing road biking, till I got a proper road bike. Now the Hybrid is hardly in use.

Comment: I shall try and see if I can get gravel oriented tread as of now till I can trade the bike for one with shocks to enjoy a bit more with off-road/ rough riding capabilities.

Comment: Would the current gearset be ok for beginner on gravel /rough road track

Comment: "Would the current gearset be ok for beginner on gravel /rough road track" — It is hard to tell without seeing what you plan to ride, and what your fitness level is. The lowest combo you have is 28/34, which is enough for many places. Remember that people ride offroad on single speeds. If nothing else, you can always carry your bike for a while.

Comment: I wonder if my hybrid can withstand gravel surface?

Comment: Thank you so much for your valuable guidance.

Comment: I'd rather take my two non-sus bikes on a blue trail than on many of the cross-country routes I've done, that include things like farm tracks and lumpy grass.

Comment: @AliHafeezAzmat You can definitely jump off curbs even with fixed forks. Just do not overdo it. 10 cm is not a problem https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wSQSZaq6IWQ

Comment: If you find yourself in a spot where 28/34 is not low enough, you're probably better off shouldering the bike and walking.

Comment: @ojs my MTB's 24/34 lowest makes lifting the front wheel or spinning the back too easy depending on where I put my weight and the surface, but 28/34 might lack a little for rough steep climbs